# Proving a circumference is not homeomorphic to two adjacent ones

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, circles

> Let $X$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$; that is $X=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$ and has the subspace topology. Consider $Y$ to be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $Y=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}\cup\{(x,y):(x-2)^2+y^2=1\} $.
>
> Is $Y$ homeomorphic to the space $X$?

I know I could use path-connectedness to prove $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic but I am not supposed to. I thought of cardinality, but I really have no clue on how to approach this problem.

**Question:**

How should I prove $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you have in mind whan you claim that you “could use path-connectedness to prove $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic”; if it is, I will delete it.

If you remove a point from $X$, what remains is connected. But if you remove $(1,0)$ from $Y$, what remains becomes disconnected.

Comment: The thing is that in this section of the book the path-connectedness definition has not been introduced yet. So I guess I could not infer that the circumferences union is disconnected without the theorem that implies that path-connectedness leads to connectedness . But thanks to the answer!

Comment: @Pedro, but in this case it's easier to show that $Y$ minus the point is not connected directly from the definition of connectedness than using path connectedness.

Comment: @PedroGomes But have you alredy mentioned connectedness?

Comment: Yes that was mentioned.

Comment: Then notice that I did not mention path-connectedness **at all** in my answer. Only connectedness.

Comment: @Ennar        So I would need to find a clopen set in $Y\setminus(1,0)$, but I have no clue on how to do it.

Comment: How do you prove $Y\setminus\{(1,0)\} $is disconnected?

Comment: That's easy: the left half of $Y$ is clopen.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not seeing how the left side of $Y$ is clopen. Could you explain it a little more detailed please?

Comment: @Pedro, do you know the definition of relative topology? Hint is to use the following open subsets of the plane: $U = \{ (x,y)\mid x<1\}$ and $V = \{ (x,y)\mid x>1\}$.

Comment: The left side of $Y$ is closed becaue it is the intersection of $Y$ with the closed halfplane $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x\leqslant0\}$ and it is open because it is the intersection of $Y$ with the open halfplane $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x<0\}$.

Comment: @ Ennar         No, I have never heard of relative topology. Are you referring to subspace topology?

Comment: @Pedro, sorry, I've mistranslated from my native language, the term in English is subspace topology.

Comment: Sorry but I was thinking of your answer and I thought that it should be instead $x\leqslant 1$ and $x<1$ once we removed the point (1,0) from Y. Is it not right?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry about that.